# rsnapshot diff between snapshots

Tags: rsnapshot, diff, forensics

I am using `rsnapshot` to manage incremental backups of some GNU/Linux servers.

Although `rsnapshot` is delivered with a tool called `rsnapshot-diff` it just provide disk space statistics.

The question is how to get a diff: new and deleted files, on a specific snapshot.

I read suggestions like

```
# find /raid/rap/$interval -type f -links 1 -exec du -k {} \; | sort -rn
```

but it didn't work on my snapshots. I did modify a single file an run the one liner above right after a new hourly.0 snapshot and no differences were reported. Alhtough if I run it as

```
# find /raid/rap/$interval -type f -links 2 -exec du -k {} \; | sort -rn
```

the modified file is reported. Why there are two links to the modified file?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this question has been answered, but just wanted to do the same thing. I used:

```
rsnapshot-diff -v folder1 folder2
```

which worked for me. Note that folder1 and folder2 are *folders* and not *snapshot names*. In my case, folder1 was `/USB/USB_HDD_7/Snapshots/daily.0`

Answer (score 1):

The problem I have with "rsnapshot-diff" or even a related "diff_backup.pl" script is they don't take into account files that were renamed and then relinked together.  They list them as added-deleted when really they were moved and re-linked together (seperate step).

However rsync itself knows when this happens and lists hardlinked but renamed files correctly...

`rsync -aHin dir2/ dir1 2>&1 | grep -v '^\.d'`

the only problem is while it lists the real changes it does not give the disk usage changes.